# Grails 2.3.11 broken image display

Tags: grails, groovy

I make a web app that with every new entry by user it creates a folder under grails-app/conf/templates/(user.id)

```
   def showImage(){
        def baseFolder = 'E:\\untitled1\\grails-app\\conf\\templates'
        def subFolder = baseFolder + '\\' + "${item.id}"
        def imageList1 = new File(subFolder).list()
        println imageList1
        def imageList = Arrays.asList(imageList1)
        println imageList
        [imageList: imageList]}
```

and here my gsp

```
<g:each in="${imageList}" status="i" var="image">

<img src="${createLinkTo(dir: 'E:\\untitled1\\grails- app\\conf\\templates\\70' , file: "${i}.png")}" alt="${i}"/>
 </g:each>
```

i put a random folder 70 in order to try a sample and it appears the correct name of the images like 0.png, 1.png ,2.png but it displays broken image symbol

Any ideas ?

Comment: I would recommend you to check directory path `def baseFolder = E:\\untitled1\\grails-app\\conf\\templates'` . the directory path you are passing in createLinkTo might be wrong.

Comment: I think that direction is correct as println is correct and plus it shows correctly how many photos there are in the folder like 3 photos in folder 70 , 5 in folder 71 . It can see the number of the images included in the file and there names but it does not display them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createLinkTo()` uses your applications name as a namespace which alone prevents this from working. Your links will end up in a form of `src="yourappname/E:..."`

Also, grails does not expose resources under `conf/` by default to web. Place your files under `web-app/templates/` and change the `createLinkTo` to `createLinkTo(dir:'templates', file: "${i}.png")`

*Please include your grails version in the description and any plugins you use.*

Comment: works perfectly , can  i ask you one more question ? Well , if user input photos like , photo1.jpg , photo2.jpg can i rename to 0.jpg,1jpg ? or how i can access them with their real name ? i mean if i println imageList[0] in controller it will display photo1.jpg , but  i cant figure out a way to do it in html ( maybe like `files: "image[${i}].jpg"` )